# What is the probability that we get $k$ heads when a coin is tossed $10$ times?

Tags: probability

I'm learning about probability and I am not sure how to approach this basic problem.

> We toss/flip a coin $10$ times. What is the probability that we get $k$ heads?

My understanding is that:

$\Theta =$ set of all possible results: in this case we have $2^{10}$ possible results.

Event indicating that we have $k$ heads ( let's say that $k = 2$ in this example ) is

$A = \{ \ldots \} = C(10,2) = 45$ (if I am not mistaken, we choose $2$ fields out of $10$ when we have heads)

How to determine the probablity of this even? is  $45 \over 2^{10}$ right answer?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's right if the coin is fair. (And assuming you mean $45/2^{10}$ rather han $45/10^2$).

If the coin is not fair (but you know the probability of flipping heads), you need a slightly more complicated formula: the *binomial distribution*.